# Doctrine SQL query: works on MySQL, on PostgreSQL won't

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, postgresql, doctrine, portability

This is a query automatically generated by Taggable extension for Doctrine ORM.

```
SELECT t.id AS t__id, t.name AS t__name, COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) AS i__0,
   (COUNT(DISTINCT i.id)) AS i__1
FROM taggable_tag t
LEFT JOIN cms__model__image_taggable_tag c ON (t.id = c.tag_id)
LEFT JOIN image i ON i.id = c.id
WHERE t.id IN
    (SELECT doctrine_subquery_alias.id
     FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id, (COUNT(DISTINCT i2.id)) AS i2__1
        FROM taggable_tag t2
        LEFT JOIN cms__model__image_taggable_tag c2 ON (t2.id = c2.tag_id)
        LEFT JOIN image i2 ON i2.id = c2.id
        GROUP BY t2.id HAVING i2__1 > 0
        ORDER BY i2__1 DESC LIMIT 10) AS doctrine_subquery_alias)
GROUP BY t.id HAVING i__1 > 0
ORDER BY i__1 DESC
```

It works when using MySql, but won't work with PostgreSql.

I get: `column i2__1 not found` or `column i__2 not found`.

Are aliases disallowed when using COUNT(DISTINCT)?
How this query should look like to work on PostgreSql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to replace `i2__1` by `COUNT(DISTINCT i2.id)` in the `HAVING`-clause of the sub-select, or remove the parenthesis around `COUNT(DISTINCT i2.id)`.

You might also have to add `t__name` to the `GROUP BY`-clause of the main select.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Is this a bug in Doctrine or my version of PostgreSql? Or just this syntax is not supported by PostgreSql at all?

Comment: Which suggestion did actually help you?

Comment: Removing parenthesis did nothing. I had to repeat COUNTs in HAVINGs instead of aliases (Will it be slower?). Obviously, t.name is needed in GROUP BY as well.

Comment: I don't think that performance is going to suffer. I don't know about SQL-Server, but Oracle also does not support the generated syntax.

Comment: I don't, either. And, frankly, with all the MySQL/Doctrine/PostgreSQL work I've been doing lately, I can tell you that such a performance hit would be nothing compared to some of the measures I've been getting on our very high end systems running MySQL through Doctrine.